# How to change border color of input/textarea on :focus?

Tags: css, reactjs

I use react and my additional CSS definitions locates in the js file as a constants like this (hope that that is not a bad practice):

```
const STYLE = {
    logo: {
        width: '206px',
        height: '73px',
        margin: '120px auto 0',
        display: 'block'
    },
    label: {
        fontSize: 'x-small'
    },
    control: {
        border: 'solid',
        borderWidth: '0 0 1px',
        borderColor: '#E0E0E0',
        width: '200px'
    }
};

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src='.../logo.gif' style={STYLE.logo}/>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Col smOffset=...>
                        <Form horizontal>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Col sm=... style={STYLE.label}>
                                    Label: 
                                    <input style={STYLE.control} type="text"/>
                                </Col>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to remove the border around the input component with CSS. I need to add the following css to my STYLE.control:

```
input:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

But I do not know how to do that because (of course) this does not work:

```
const STYLE = {
    noBorder: {
        input:focus: 'outline:none'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I went through some styling in React documentation it seems that the best option to solve this issue is using [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium).

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <style>
               input:focus {
                 outline: none;
               }
              </style>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. I know that I can use external css file or add this content to the header tags on the index page but i do not want to do that. I would like to add it somehow to my react js file.

Comment: Ah ok. Well you could put a <style></style> section within your render method. Then it would be in your react.js file. Would the comply with what you are looking for?

Comment: It does not work. SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected }. Complains about the ":" character after "outline".